# finding the words with given letters in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to coding , can you help me with this small JavaScript code?
the problem that I am facing is that I can't console.log the words in the arr array

```
var arr =["wide","wiiii", "dwww", "not"]
var lett = ["i","w","d","e"]
var c = 0;
for(  i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  for ( x=0;x<arr[i].length;x++){
    for (z=0;z<lett.length;z++){
      if (arr[i][x]==lett[z] ){
        c++
        if(c == lett.length-1){
          console.log(arr[i])
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

the output should look like this

```
wide
wiiii
dwww
```

@Vishnudev I found the error:
the code that you gave me logs the words that have AT LEAST one letter that is in the lett [], and that's not what I want.
see, if in the words array there is ["wide","wzzxx","this word has the letter j in it"] your code gives this output:

```
wide
wzzxx
this word has the letter j in it
```

but what I need is this as output :

```
wide
```

Comment: What's the logic? Contains one letter? Contains all letters? Contains at least one letter?

Comment: it must contain just the letters in lett[]

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
const arr =["wide","wiiii", "dwww", "not"];
const lett = ["i","w","d","e"];

const values = arr.filter(word => word.split('').every(c => lett.includes(c)));

console.log(values.join('\n'));
```

Comment: You can make it simpler : `arr.filter(word => lett.some(l => word.includes(l)))`. No need to split the string.

Comment: this works just for small data, look here
https://siasky.net/OADhUHKcAoRzzMqjgCk_3qEjvHR_dW3sJzPvHBqDoQWgig
it logs all the words, do you have any solution?

Comment: Why don't you make a JSfiddle or a Codepen instead of sharing a link of a test you uploaded to a server?

Comment: @big_brother4123e What do you mean it works just for small data. This will work for data of any size.

Comment: @Vishnudev
https://jsfiddle.net/cL8duax0/
as you can see in the output there are words that contain letters that are not in the lett array for example the letter "g"

Comment: @Vishnudev i didn't explain myself better before, I have updated the post , the problem with your code is that basically it logs out even words that have letters that are not in the lett []

Comment: There isn't any problem with my code. It was according to what you had asked. Now that you have modified the requirements, I'll update my answer. @big_brother4123e

Comment: yes, the problem was not with your code, I just, didn't think about providing you with a better example